# How can I include a hyperlink in a Growl notification?

Tags: perl, growl, growl-for-windows

I couldn't find any code to do so on Growl's documentation (which IMO is pretty terrible), nor in the Perl libraries on CPAN. The most recently updated Perl module, [Growl::GNTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Growl%3A%3AGNTP) doesn't show any code snippet that would enable [custom displays](http://growl.info/documentation/webkit.php), which is apparently how formatting links should be done.

I know though that it's [possible](https://stackapps.com/questions/820/soapi-notify-stay-ahead-of-the-pack-with-new-question-notification-v1-release) to include hyperlinks in Growl notifications, despite what [some say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050676/inline-styling-of-growl-notifications).

Perl or PHP code preferred.

Comment: A snippet of the code you're using would be helpful here. What have you tried?

Comment: I've wasted about an hour with Growl::GNTP, but it seems that the way to go is to use [custom displays](http://growl.info/documentation/webkit.php) and I couldn't find any Perl library support for those; nor did the example in that link work on Windows either. I've posted on [growl-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/growldiscuss) but they're moderating new messages.

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifically targeting Growl on Windows, or just generic GNTP? It doesn't really matter though since the sending app can't specify the display - that is up to the receiver (user). The link you provided to that soapi notifier is using its own custom display style, which the user would then have to set as their preferred display (at least for that notification type). When you write a custom display, you can include links or anything you want. On Windows, custom displays have to be written in .NET and on OSX, they can be either Obj-C or html.

Comment: I'm targeting Windows, and I'm not going to learn .NET just to display a hyperlink in a Growl notification; that would be retarded. It was easier to port the project to JavaScript and use [Chrome desktop notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13328513/1269037).

Comment: I am glad you came up with a workable solution, but I think you were coming at it from the wrong side. If your app is the one sending notifications, you cant really control how it is displayed - that is what Growl is for; it lets the *user* decide how they want the notifications displayed (some may not even use a visual display at all). Also, if you simply wanted the notification to perform some action when clicked, Growl already does the by default for all visual notification types - no hyperlink needed.

Comment: But if you need to control the display of the notification as well, then bypassing Growl and rolling your own notifications (or using the Chrome notifications, etc) is the better way to go.